# Crawl data from a website using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler

I would like to crawl some data from a website. To manually access the target data, I need to log in and then click on some buttons on to finally get the target html page. Currently, I am using the Python `request` library to simulate this process. I am doing like this:

```
ss = requests.session()
#log in
resp = ss.post(url, data = (('username', 'xxx'), ('password', 'xxx')))
#then send requests to the target url
result = ss.get(taraget_url)
```

However, I found that the final request did not return me what I want.

So I changed the method. I download all the network traffic and look into the headers and cookies of the last request. I found that here are some contents that are different in each log in session like the `sessionid` and some other variables. So I traces back when these varibales are returned in the response and then get the values again by sending the corresponding requests. After this, I construct the correct headers and cookies and then send request like this:

```
resp = ss.get(target_url, headers = myheader, cookies = mycookie)
```

But still, it does not return me anything. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same boat some time ago, and I eventually switched from trying to get requests to work to using Selenium instead, which made life much easier. (`pip install selenium`). Then you can log into a website and then navigate to a desired website like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

website_with_logins = "https://website.com"
website_to_access_after_login = "https://website.com/page"

driver.get( str(website_with_logins) )
username = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
username.send_keys("your_username")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password.send_keys("your_password")
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.get( str(website_to_access_after_login) )
```

Once you have the `website_to_access_after_login` loaded (you'll see it appear), you can get the html and have a field day using just

`html = driver.page_source`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had tried to use selenium and I managed to accomplish what I need. However, I need to put this script on a Linux server and schedule it once a day. So I finally switch from selenium to this....

Comment: Why can't you run Selenium from a Linux server?

Comment: I used selenium in a rather stupid manner-by  simulating the mouse click and keyboard press. So my program requires opening the browser. My question is that do you think selenium can hanle the aspnet module? Because after I log in, I will be directed to a .aspx webpage. I am not familiar with that. Thanks.

Comment: Some quick searches suggest that others have worked with aspx pages using Selenium. What do you wish to accomplish after you access the page of interest?

Comment: But selenium requires opening the browser, right? What if I would like to let the program run when the PC is locked or put it on a Linux server (the target website only allow IE access).
And after I log in the website, I will click some buttons on the asp.net frame and finally reach the target webpage. During this process, I think there are mainly some java-scripts.

Comment: Selenium does open browsers, but you should be able to run it on a Linux server, provided selenium and all dependencies are installed on the server. You can evoke IE with Selenium, and you can use Selenium to engage with javascript. If you are dead-set on making requests your package of choice, you may be able to get it going for your use case, but I have found Selenium *MUCH* easier to work with. Can you post links to the sites you want to engage with?

Comment: But the website requires log in. I do not know if it has any help only looking at the login webpage. Anyway, I will try your suggestion at first to say whether selenium can make it. Thanks very much.